# http.request post method not responding with no error on callback

Tags: node.js, http-post, httprequest, hapi.js

I want to make a POST call to my REST API running on another port in my pc. The http.get method works fine but when I make a POST request the server returns no response or any error in callback. Here is my code:

```
server.route({
method:'POST',
path:'/path1',
handler: function(req, res){
    var post_data = querystring.stringify({
        'name': 'asd',
        'price': '123'
    });
    var options = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 2000,
        path: '/apipath',
        method:'POST',
        header:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };


     var post_req = http.request(options, function(reply){
            console.log('222');
            reply.setEncoding('utf8');
            reply.on('data', function (body) {
                console.log('Body: ' + body);
        });
        post_req.write(post_data);
        post_req.end();
        res(reply);
        post_req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        });
    });

}
});
```

Comment: am not sure why (yet), but I would recommend looking at h2o2 plugin: https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2
 It's meant as a proxy handler for hapi.js and should be exactly what you need (see the Usage section)

Comment: The Hapi ecosystem proposes [Wreck](https://github.com/hapijs/wreck) to handle HTTP requests. However, what'd be interesting for debugging is the code executed by the call to `/apipath:2000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to see any error or response because you are streaming your response and ending the request inside the http.request() where as it should be like this...

```
...
...
...

var post_req = http.request(options, function(reply){
    console.log('222');
    reply.setEncoding('utf8');
    reply.on('data', function (body) {
        console.log('Body: ' + body);
    });            
});

post_req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});

post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();

...
...
```

As said in comments you have other modules for making http request in hapi